# CSS Marquee second group not showing

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So basically, the second group doesn't show when I add the animation to the div. If inspect it is there, and if I set the width for each group as 50% then they show next to each other. But when its 100% (logically I can't see the second group in this case, since its outside the screen width) I doesn't show up (It is actually there when I inspect it, moving and coming into the screen, but nothing shows up).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="work-banner">
      <ul class="work_banner_content">
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="work_banner_content">
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
         <li>Work ·</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

ul {
   list-style: none;
}

.work-banner{
   margin-top: 10px;
   border-top: solid black;
   height: 30px;
   width: 100%;
   --gap: 1rem;
   display: flex;
   overflow: hidden;
   gap: var(--gap);

   /* animation: test 15s linear infinite; */
}
 
 .work_banner_content {
   font-weight: 600;
   flex-shrink: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   min-width: 100%;
   gap: var(--gap);
 }

 .work_banner_content li{
   width: 12.5%;
 } 

 @keyframes test {
   from {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
   }
   to {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
   }
 }
```

Comment: I imagine this is due to the `overflow: hidden;` on the `.work-banner`.

Answer (score 0):

The overflowing content is being hidden by the `overflow: hidden;` rule on `.work-banner`. To avoid that (without having to re-work your parent element styles) you could simply apply the same animation to each of the `.work_banner_content` elements instead of the parent:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.work-banner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  --gap: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.work_banner_content {
  font-weight: 600;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-width: 100%;
  gap: var(--gap);
  animation: test 15s linear infinite; /* The content is now the animated element */
}

.work_banner_content li {
  width: 12.5%;
}

@keyframes test {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="work-banner">
  <ul class="work_banner_content">
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="work_banner_content">
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
    <li>Work ·</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you !! its a bit stupid since, when entering the screen, it shouldn't be considered overflow anymore. But who am I to say.

Comment: @Leaf420 Well, the rule is styling the overflow of the container not the screen, and you are moving the container by animating it. But glad this helped!